# Mercurial 2.3 - why is {latesttag} null?

Tags: mercurial

I use `hg parents --template {latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}` to get me a version file. I get `null+78`.

This is what `hg parents` gets me:

```
changeset:   79:74a86aec9582
tag:         0.8.010
tag:         tip
user:        XYZ
date:        Mon Sep 10 14:48:03 2012 +0200
summary:     jQuery, jQuery UI, and jqGrid updates completed as basis
```

**Why do I not get the** `0.8.010 tag+1`?

[image: Mercurial visual]

The `latesttag` approach is standard as described here:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4367747/356726
2. [How do I get the latest Mercurial tag from within Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180786/how-do-i-get-the-latest-mercurial-tag-from-within-powershell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`hg help templates`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/templating) defines `latesttag` as:

> Most recent global tag in the ancestors of this changeset.

It appears that `0.8.010` is a local tag only (there is no commit creating a global tag).  Local tags do not show up in `{latesttag}`.

Comment: Can I somehow see whether a tag is local or global?

Comment: @HorstWalter: local tags are stored in the `<repo root>/.hg/localtags` file.  Global tags are stored in `<repo root>/.hgtags`.  See http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag for details.